# Function is no longer found if I add "require" source

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function "loadDays()" that should be executed when the body-section is loaded:

```
<body onload="loadDays()">
```

In `<script>` I have my function `loadDays()`:

```
<script>
    function loadDays() {
        // code
    }
```

Now I added `src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"` to the `<script>`-tag, to make use of `require` inside my function.

While it does recognize `require` then, it throws a new error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: loadDays is not defined
>
> ```
> at onload
> ```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If `<script>` tag has `src` attribute, then any content inside this tag is ignored.

You should add 2 separate tags:

```
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadDays() {
        // code
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I do that, how can I get the variable from the first `<script>` tag to the second one?
Cause I need that one inside of loadDays.

Comment: @User10xC If it's in global scope - just use it. If it's in isolated scope, then there is no way to access it

Comment: How do I make it global scope?

Comment: Like this is what I have right now:

    <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js">
        const Excel = require('exceljs');
    </script>

I need  `Excel` to be available inside `loadDays()`

Comment: It's already in global scope

Comment: But it says: 

Uncaught ReferenceError: Excel is not defined
    at loadDays

Comment: @User10xC Please post another question with full information about your issue

Comment: I can't it says that I'm not allowed to open another question.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked requireJS, so you should actually do it like this, as they said in the docs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             scripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then add a main.js file in the scripts folder, and put your function inside of it.

```
    function loadDays() {
        // code
    }
```